# react-bootstrap-typeahead restrict input to only numbers

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-typeahead

Using the react-bootstrap-typeahead

```
<Typeahead
    {...this.state}
    id="basic-example"
    onChange={id => this.setState({ id })}
    options={id}
    placeholder="Select ID"
/>
```

is to possible to restrict the input of Typeahead to only numbers? if yes, provide an overview how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set the `inputProps`:

```js
<Typeahead
  {...this.state}
  id="basic-example"
  inputProps={{
    type: 'number',
  }}
  onChange={id => this.setState({ id })}
  options={id}
  placeholder="Select ID"
/>
```

Comment: inputProps didn't work, no error in console, i can still type alphabets, is there anything to be added for this to work?

Comment: @sumanth, works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-morning-qmj7q